# Power BI--have a report showing 1 month; want to create PDF showing all months

Tags: powerbi, report, pdf-generation

Very simple question. Not sure if there is a way to do this.
Management requested a PDF with 12 months of data, each month on a separate page. (Past data will often be updated to reflect recent activity, so the past month's reports aren't static.)

I've created a Power BI report showing 1 month of data at a time, with a slicer to allow user to choose the month.

I'd like to export all 12 months to a single PDF file in one step. I don't want to have to create 12 different reports, or have the user cycle through all the months on the slicer to get the report.

Is there a way to do this?  I can't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to accomplish this in a standard Power BI report. A paginated report in Power BI (or legacy SSRS report builder) is likely a better tool for this. You can use the groups feature to group the report on year, creating a different page of the same report for each year.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15